# Need to delete all empty subdirectories using perl in windows

Tags: windows, perl, directory-structure, file-handling

```
while (defined($name = readdir $dh)) {
    next unless -d "$root/$name";
    $dir=$root.$name."/";
    if(is_folder_empty($dir)){
        print"$dir is Empty\n";
        print"Do you want to delete it? 1-Yes 2-No\n";
        $aa=<STDIN>;
        chomp $aa;
        if($aa==1){
            $deleteregdir = "$dir";
            rmdir $deleteregdir;
            print"Directory has been deleted!!\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print"$dir is NOT Empty\n";
        $dir2=$dir;
        opendir my $dh2, $dir2;
        while (defined($name2 = readdir $dh2)) {
            next unless -d "$dir2/$name2";
            $dd=$dir2.$name2."/";
            #print"$dd\n";
            if(is_folder_empty($dd)){
                print"$dd is Empty\n";
                print"Do you want to delete it? 1-Yes 2-No\n";
                $aa=<STDIN>;
                chomp $aa;
                if($aa==1){
                    $deleteregdir = "$dir";
                    rmdir $deleteregdir;
                    print"Directory has been deleted!!\n";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print"$dd is NOT Empty\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code only runs for directory and its sub directory. The iteration stops in the next level. I want to search all empty directories. I want the structure to be such that when I run the code, all directories that are empty are deleted after getting a confirmation from the user.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know about subroutines and recursion?

Comment: Have you tried `File::Find`?

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use a module, [File::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aUtil) makes this sort of thing very easy.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Util;

my $path = '...';

my $fu         = File::Util->new();
my @all_dirs   = $fu->list_dir($path, '--recurse', '--dirs-only');
my @empty_dirs = grep { not $fu->list_dir($_) } @all_dirs;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
perl -MFile::Find -e"finddepth(sub{rmdir},'.')"
```

and see nice [explanation](http://duramecho.com/ComputerPrograms/DeleteEmptyDirectories/).